# hiding a form input on click outside of its onlclick div

Tags: reactjs

I have a form composed of a one input, and I want to toggle it. The form displays when you click on div, and I want to hide the form when i click outside of `div`. How do I do that in React?

```
class InputToggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showInputForm: false
    };
  }
  onClickAction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showInputForm: true });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.showInputForm) {
      return (<input type="text" />)
    }
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClickAction.bind(this)}>
        <h1>value</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How to set the state `showInputForm` to false on a click outside of `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `onBlur` event listener on the input element. See code:

```
class InputToggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showInputForm: false
    };
  }
  onClickAction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showInputForm: true });
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.showInputForm) {
      this.input.focus();
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.showInputForm) {
      return (
        <input
          ref={(el) => this.input = el}
          onBlur={() => this.setState({ showInputForm: false })}
          type="text" />
      );
    }
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClickAction.bind(this)}>
        <h1>value</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I had to focus the input when it is rendered. The `onBlur` event won't be fired if the input is not in focus.

See working [pen](https://codepen.io/danegit/pen/XZKxRW).